# How do I do prediction after fitting TfidfVectorizer and KMeans in Scikit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a training data set which is in Pandas Dataframe. I have done TfIdf Vectorization to get features and run Kmeans. Here is the relevant code:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=max_feat, norm="l1", analyzer="word",
                                 min_df=0.1,ngram_range=(1,2)
                                 )

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['reviews'])
km = KMeans(n_clusters=number, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=3,
                    verbose=1, n_jobs = -2)
km.fit(X)
```

I can get the centroids through this:

```
order_centroids = km.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
```

Now, when I try to run the test data I get error. Here is the code I'm running for test data. I'm basically taking each row from the test dataframe of Panda and fitting into the same vectorizer above. Am I doing it wrong?

```
sample = df.tail(int(totalTestRows * lineLimit))

for row in sample.itertuples():
    test_data = np.array([row[6]])
    testVectorizerArray = vectorizer.transform(test_data).toarray()
    rowX = vectorizer.fit(testVectorizerArray)
    print(km.predict(rowX))
```

On the `rowX = vectorizer.fit(testVectorizerArray)` line, I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I searched through StackOverflow and it seems that I need to format the `test_data` array as an one dimensional array. I've checked and test_data is of the form `(n,)`. However, I'm still getting error. Is there anything wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be refitting the vectorizer in the test stage, your code would be cleaner if you combine the vectorizer and classifier with a pipeline:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=max_feat, norm="l1", analyzer="word",
                                 min_df=0.1,ngram_range=(1,2)
                                 )   
km = KMeans(n_clusters=number, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=3,
                    verbose=1, n_jobs = -2)
clf = make_pipeline(vectorizer, km)
clf.fit(X)


sample = df.tail(int(totalTestRows * lineLimit))

for row in sample.itertuples():
    test_data = np.array([row[6]])
    print(clf.predict(test_data))
```

Comment: But `row[6]` is a string. Therefore I need to get its TfIdf with respect to the whole training data to see how it scores for the selected features. Your solution works. But what was the problem with my approach?

Comment: when you do `fit` the first time with the training data, the vectorizer stores the term frequencies and the vocabularies, and it uses these stored values when you call predict later on.

Comment: Okay. Yes, that's what I wanted to do. Do you know which function it calls internally on `vectorizer` for `test_data`. By the way, thank you so much. I was struggling in understanding this very much.

Comment: no worries, inside pipeline it internally calls `fit_transform` the first time, then just `transform` the other times

Comment: Okay but I did the same thing. I called `fit_transform` on `vectorizer` and then `predict` on `km`. But it didn't work. Do you mean it calls `transform` on `vectorizer` once again after `fit_transform`? I just wanted to know the manual steps. I do understand that your code looks much organized.

Comment: I think your original code would work if you delete the line `rowX = vectorizer.fit(testVectorizerArray)` and change the last line to `print(km.predict(testVectorizerArray))`

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: oh actually i didn't read your code properly, it's actually not correct to iterate through your sample like this, you're meant to score it all at once, see my edit

Comment: Okay but what is the reason behind this?